Combining term structure types in Quantlib
Is it possible to combine multiple term structure types for curve construction in quantlib?
Specifically I want to be able to construct an OIS curve that is stepped in the short end with pillars at central bank meeting dates - and interpolated past say the 1 year point.
For example I would like to use the PiecewiseFlatForward curve type for the stepped part, and the PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount beyond.

Currently there's no way to combine an interpolation on forwards with an interpolation on discounts.  There is a MixedInterpolation class in the underlying C++ library that could join two different interpolations on the same quantities (i.e., on forwards for both parts, or on discounts for both parts) but it seems to only support a few combinations and it's not fully exported to Python.

Thanks Luigi, much appreciated.
To get around this I am toying with a two stage process whereby I fit the meeting dates first (with PiecewiseFlatForward), extract all the one day fwds until the last meeting date and feed them in as inputs to stage 2 with the DatedOISHelper to force constant rates between meeting dates.

This is already implement in QuantLib: Issue
You can also find some discussions here
ql.PiecewiseLogMixedLinearCubicDiscount(date, helpers, calendar, [], [], ql.LogMixedLinearCubic(n, ql.MixedInterpolation.SplitRanges)) # jumps and jumpDates are empty

Similar for
PiecewiseLogMixedLinearCubicDiscount
